# Local multithreaded server: how make it simple?

Tags: pthreads, client-server, epoll

There is a task - i need a client-server apps with properties below:

- client uses blocking sockets
- server is passive: he accepts incoming connections, gets some data, processes it and sends results back
- server has several threads (except main), from 1 to about 100
- all actions is onto one machine, i.e. **both client and server use localhost**
- max size of data transfered is about **1 KB**

At the beginning I've implemented epoll-based server:

- main thread does IO using epoll, worker threads do data processing
- all server sockets are non-blocking
- server has two queues: incoming where main thread puts client request, outcoming from where main thread gets replies.

I's works but then I thought about that design again: it doesn't take into account localhost. It's more universal and therefore more complicated. It would be nice to do it simpler than it is.

So:

- main thread does epoll_wait, accept and manages a connection queue. The connection queue is a queue where main thread puts accepted connections
- listening socket is non-blocking. accepted sockets are blocking
- when any socket becomes readable main thread wakes up worker thread, worker does recv in blocking mode, processing and send in blocking mode.

What do you think about it? Is that design good enough?

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Just throw the multi threading thing out the window. There is no need to involve multi threading until you are computationally bound. It's a net negative in terms of performance to involve threads prematurely, and adds a huge complexity to the project. Just do all the work on the main thread and use epoll to multiplex your I/O.

Comment: Eric, are you talking about using threads for IO?